# saveAsTextFile not working with variable path

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, oozie, rdd, hue

I am trying to save a RDD to text file using saveAsTextFile

```
  rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile(path);
```

I have a shell script with spark submit command in it.

Command line
 - It is working fine when I run the script using command line in client or cluster mode, with Hardcoded path(HDFS location) as well as passing path parameters to my class.

Using Shell Action in Oozie/Hue
 - It is working fine when I run the job with HARDCODED path to HDFS location.

It is not working when I pass the path parameter to my class and use it in saveAsTextFile. Though oozie action shows success but I am not seeing any output at that location.
I tried broadcasting the path parameters too, it worked in command line but not in Oozie shell action.

I wanted to pass the path parameters and get the desired result at that location using Oozie/Hue.

Comment: Did you check the launcher job (launched by Oozie) logs. You need to go into the individual mapper and see the logs. `stdout` and `strerr`. You might need to share your shell action and relevant properties. Thanks.

Comment: try this : `rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://ip-address:port/path")`